# Static Analyzer error with iOS8 SDK

Tags: static, clang, ios8, xcode6, analyzer

Recently I updated to Xcode 6 beta 6 with iOS 8 SDK. And while running static analyser I jumped into a problem with the following errors.

error: error reading 'pic'
error: no analyzer checkers are associated with '-mrelocation-model'
2 errors generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Any Idea what is these errors and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770938/build-error-with-xcode-6-and-possibly-cocoapods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It´s a issue with the clang static analyzer. 
Add to your existing analyzer entry under "Target" -> "Build Phases" -> "Compiler Flags" the suffix `-Xanalyzer deadcode`.

Complete entry should read as follows:
`-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer deadcode`

Comment: If I add these flags the error mentioned above does not appear. However, the static analyzer issues return. Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d).

Answer (score 2):

I have solve this problem recently you can solve using go to Xcode > Preferences > Location and remove all derived data in derived data folder and then clean and analyze

Comment: Didn't work for me. This seems to be an issue specific to this version upgrade (including the first non-beta version). I ran into it with CocoaPods, although it could perhaps happen in other situations.

Comment: I have xcode version for beta Version 6.0 (6A280n) my issue resolve by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

With the above answers in Xcode 8, I noticed build errors when using Swift compilation. Here's what Compiler Flags worked for me:

```
-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks
```