# Build error with Xcode 6 and (possibly) cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode6

I'm getting the following static analyzer error when building my iOS project that is using cocoapods with the latest Xcode 6 GM release.

```
error: error reading 'pic'
error: no analyzer checkers are associated with '-mrelocation-model'
2 errors generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I can disable the static analyzer, but obviously I don't want to do that. Does anyone know how to fix this ( or a workaround ) and what exactly is causing this error?

Comment: Having the same problem here. Not sure what to do about it though so hopefully someone chimes in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a known issue with a fix already in the queue for the next version of Cocoapods.  Check out the [bug report](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2402) for more info.

Supposedly you can work around this in the meantime by re-enabling warnings (e.g remove `inhibit_all_warnings` from your podspec).

Alternatively, and what turned out to be the real problem for me, was that I had a deprecated flag set on a couple of the files.  I removed these flags and the build succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Evan. Not sure though how to fix this in my current project. The pods I'm using don't have `inhibit_all_warnings` in their podspec. Additionally I don't use those offending compiler flags you mentioned on any of my project files.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2402#issuecomment-55412661) on the bug, it will be fixed in the next release of CocoaPods.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Yes, but how do I get this fixed immediately?